# IBAction Delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have a problem with IBAction delegate. I create button in xib file by Interface Builder and want to use it in another controller.

Button is clickable and I don't see any error but it don't show Alert or NSLog. If I try to do NSLog in LetterView.m, It's work perfectly fine but not in ViewController. What should i do?

Thanks for help.

What I am doing currently is:

**LetterView.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h> 

@class LettersView; 

@protocol ButtonHint <NSObject>

-(void)hintButtonView:(LettersView*)letterView; 

@end

@interface LettersView : UIView @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *lettersView;

- (IBAction)hintButton:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)removeButton:(id)sender;

@property (nonatomic, assign) id <ButtonHint> hintDelegate; 

@end
```

**LetterView.m**

```
-(IBAction)hintButton:(id)sender {
    [self.hintDelegate hintButtonView:self];
}
```

**ViewController.h**

```
@interface GameViewController : UIViewController <ButtonDisplayChar, ButtonHint>
```

**ViewController.m**

```
-(void)hintButtonView:(LettersView *)letterView {
    NSLog(@"DSfdfsadasda");
    [self addAlert:@"HINT" andMessage:helpstr andButton:@"Thanks"];
}
```

Comment: Did you assign hintDelegate ?

Comment: Where i should do it?

Comment: In the  view controller you need to set `yourLetterViewObject.hintDelegate = self;`

Comment: You are the best! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can do in other View controller by adding target of that Button
example : in your xib have button.

Use that button as target in other view controller.

**example :**
first in view controller

```
var letterVw     : LetterView?

letterVw.myFirstButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(myClass.pressed(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

than

```
func pressed(sender: UIButton!) {

}
```